# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Gender_id'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning Web App development with asp.net mvc & Entity Framework. I have a database with 3 tables students, genders & programs. I encountered this problem.

***Error is on Line 23.***

> Invalid column name 'Genders_Id'.
>   Invalid column name 'Programs_Id'.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Genders_Id'.
>   Invalid column name 'Programs_Id'.
>
> ```
> Source Error:
>
>
> Line 21:         {
> Line 22:             StudentsContext stdContext = new StudentsContext();
> Line 23:             Students students = stdContext.Students.Single(std => std.Id == id);
> Line 24:             //ViewBag.Student = students;
> Line 25:             return View(students);
> ```

My code for Students.cs Model:

```
namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
  public class Students
  {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Gender { get; set; }
     public int Program { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
   }
}
```

My Context.cs file:

```
public class StudentsContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Students> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Programs> Programs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genders> Genders { get; set; }
}
```

Programs.cs:

```
public class Programs
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Genders.cs:

```
public class Genders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Database tables:

[image]

Comment: Could you also post `Programs` and `Genders` class code? thanks

Comment: @D-Shih edited my post with the code.

Comment: @IvanStoev Fixed.

Comment: is it dbfirst or codefirst ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad db was created first, the columns and table related to programs and gender were added later

Comment: so you have generated the DbContext and other classes manually or using the Wizard in VS ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am extremely but I didnt understand you. I created the database using MS Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: @DanialAhmed please look at step 4 in this article if you have done that approach : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/database-first-approach-in-entity-framework/

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Isnt doing that step 4 and adding connection string Web.Config same thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179686/discussion-between-ehsan-sajjad-and-danial-ahmed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Genders_Id` and `Programs_Id` are the default EF6 conventional names of FK columns for the one to many relationships introduced respectively by the `Genders.Students` and `Programs.Students` collection navigation properties.

Since your FK property / column names are not conventional, you should specify them by either `[ForeinKey]` data annotations:

```
public class Programs
{
    // ...
    [ForeignKey("Program")]
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Genders
{
    // ...
    [ForeignKey("Gender")]
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

or (my preferred) fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<Genders>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Students)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.Gender);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Programs>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Students)
        .WithRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.Program);
}
```

Comment: But I didnt use foreign key in database, I was about to implement it but wanted to retrieve students data but I encountered this problem

Comment: Not sure what is happening but after specifying foreign key (Even though I didnt implement foreign key in database) It is working fine. Thanks

Comment: @DanialAhmed he means by default EF will consider the foreign key id in the class as property like Program_Id or Student_Id but you have not defined those as convention so you need to explicitly tell which column is foreign key for those

Comment: When you map to existing database (not maintained by EF code migrations), it's more important what EF thinks database structure is (based on entity model metadata) then what's the actual database structure. Although the best is to keep them in sync :) Mapping the columns as FKs allows EF to correctly join the related tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your **issue** is that your connection string in data layer and connection string in web layer are pointing to different databases.

e.g. data layer reading dev database webapp pointing to test database.

**either update connection strings to point to the same database**

or

make sure your both database have same tables and columns